# Android recyclerView.addOnScrollListener giving error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a recyclerView on my app and need to create a Endless list with it. 
i used the recyclerView.addOnScrollListener

But i am getting the following error for it.

```
Cannot resolve method 'addOnScrollListener(anonymous android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnScrollListener)'
```

My code

```
// Setup RecyclerView News
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewDesigns);
        // improve performance if you know that changes in content
        // do not change the size of the RecyclerView
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
 recyclerViewAdapter = new CatAdapter(Categories_page.this, arrayOfLatestnews);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            }
        });
```

Searched and googled alot, but i cant found the solution for it. Anybody help please.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: post you code where you have tried

Comment: have you added RecyclerView in gradle ?

Comment: yes, RecyclerView working fine. it loads first 10 items. I want to add next 10 while it scrolled down.

Comment: do you have any controls for that, like up and down buttons

Comment: it is `setOnScrollListener` and if you are looking for endless scrolling have a look here http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/01/endless-recyclerview-onscrolllistener.html

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with my endless list with RecyclerView.
Try using another version of the RecyclerView library on your gradle file.

```
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest support library (23.1.1) the `OnScrollListener` should implement two methods.

```
onScrollStateChanged
onScrolled
```

So if you update to the latest and implement the methods the issue should be resolved. Tried it now and its working. Good luck